# How to convert a string properly instead of MutableString

Tags: python

Im trying to incorporate my encryption program into a chat program. But i cant pass a MutableString with Socket. So how would I properly covert my MutableString into a proper string?

```
import sys
from UserString import MutableString

def GetMode():

while True:
    print '\n(E)ncrypt Or (D)ecrypt?'
    Mode = raw_input().lower()
    if Mode in 'e d encrypt decrypt'.split():
        return Mode
    else:
        print '\nEnter Proper Choice!'

def GetInput():
    while True:
        print '\n(T)ype Message Or (L)oad File?'
        Input = raw_input().lower()
        if Input in 't type'.split():
            Input = raw_input('>')
            return Input
        elif Input in 'l load'.split():
            MsgLoc = raw_input()
            MsgLoc = open(MsgLoc, 'r')
            try:
                Input = MsgLoc.read()
                MsgLoc.close()
                return Input
            except:
                print '\nCould Not Open' , MsgLoc
        else:
            print '\nEnter Proper Choice!'

def GetKey():
    while True:
        Key = 0
        print '\nPlease Enter A 20 Digit Number...\n** Do NOT use zeros!!!! EX-NAY ERO-ZAY! **'
        try:
            Key = int(input())
            Key = str(Key)
            if (len(Key) == 20):
                return Key
            else:
                print('\nPlease Enter A Valid Number!')
        except:
            print('\nPlease Enter A Valid Number!')

def Translate(Mode, Input, Key):
    if Mode[0] == 'e':
        print('\nEncrypting....')
        Encrypt(Input, Key)
    else:
        print('\nDecrypting....')
        Decrypt(Input, Key)

def Encrypt(Input, Key):
    Msg = MutableString()
    NonMutMsg = Input
    Msg += NonMutMsg
    MsgLen = len(Msg)
    CypherKey = Key
    a = 0
    b = 19

    #Loop For Proccessing Key
    for z in range(10):
        KeySkip = int(CypherKey[a])
        KeyIncrement = int(CypherKey[b])
        c = MsgLen/KeySkip
        d = -1

        #Loop To Skip Then Increment
        for y in range(c):
            d = d+KeySkip
            LtrNum = ord(NonMutMsg[d])
            LtrNum = LtrNum + KeyIncrement
            Msg[d] = chr(LtrNum)
```

Comment: Why are you using MutableString anyway? It's deprecated, dog slow and "[t]he main intention of this class is to serve as an educational example" (see the docs). Also, doubling the LOC by adding an unneeded blank line after *every* line is harmful - and the sheer amount of code doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as the [MutableString documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserString.MutableString) states:

> It should be noted that these classes are highly inefficient compared to real string or Unicode objects; this is especially the case for MutableString.

and most importantly:

> The main intention of this class is to serve as an educational example for inheritance

In other words, don't use this class in real world code.

To get the data out, use the `data` parameter:

```
pythonstring = mutablestring.data
```